# To add security to SSH-keys from Man-in-middle-attacks

Tags: security, ssh-keys

I would like to get Mobile-phone verification or something else besides the SSH-key verification.

**How can you add defence to the SSH-keys?**

Comment: What do you mean that someone is spoofing you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Two Factor Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-step_verification) to improve the security of ssh keys (and other authentication methods). I use Duo's [two factor authentication](https://www.duosecurity.com/). It's free for a limited number of users and is relatively cheap beyond that. It can be installed in a wide variety of OS/Applications etc. There are other 2FA products available.

Answer (score 3):

I found that hardware two-factor tokens work well.  I chose the [yubikey](http://yubico.com), because it was reasonably inexpensive, had no licensing costs over and above the initial hardware purchase, required no specialist client-side software except a USB port, and I was entirely responsible for key management and distribution; I had to reposit my trust in noone except myself.

You can find a more detailed writeup [here](http://www.teaparty.net/technotes/yubikey.html), if you want the technical nitty-gritty.  (Disclaimer: I have no connection to yubico at all, save as a satisfied customer.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe adding a one-time passcode authentication PAM (ex. https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/) to your system will give you some extra "layer of security".